# Is there a best practice for conditionally loading JS components in Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries, accordion, zurb-foundation

As per the subject, I'm trying to conditionally load a specific JS component (in this case, [**Section - Accordion**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html)) from Foundation 4 below a specific breakpoint, i.e.:

- If the user's resolution is >= 768px, don't load the JS component; or if it's already loaded, unload it
- If the user's resolution is < 768px, load (or re-load) the JS component

Right now, I'm using [**enquire.js**](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) to match/unmatch media queries in JS and respond appropriately with a Foundation load or unload (`$(document).foundation( 'section', 'off' )`) call.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. I've looked through the Zurb documentation, their Github issues list, and here on SO, but haven't found a "built-in" mechanism for this yet. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or confirm that my approach is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

I can pretty much guarantee that there is no built in method for this - I actually came here to point you toward enquire.js, which I've used for similar purposes. I don't think you'll find a better solution. Let's cross our fingers for F5.